# Spark on HDInsight. Why my edited spark-defaults.conf gets overwritten?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I have a Spark cluster running on Azure HDInsight (Windows).
I had to edit `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in `spark-defaults.conf` to add the path to a dependencies folder (JDBC driver). This works great, but every once in a while this file gets overwritten and I lose my changes. Values go to original ones.

Is this behavior expected? Why is this happening? Is this particular to Windows deployments of Spark? Can I safely turn off this behavior?

Comment: This is not normal or expected at all. Certainly nothing in Spark will write to that file. What happens to the file? It becomes empty? In a mint Spark the file does not exist, there is just `spark-defaults.conf.template`.

Comment: Yeah, it is weird. It goes back to the default values

Answer (score 0):

This is expected due to vm reimage. You have to customize the cluster during the provision process.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-provision-clusters/#advanced-configuration-options

Comment: No, I do not think is related with a reimage. Most of the times no more than 5 mins pass from the point I edit the new values to when the file is overwritten and my app stops working.